# How i can i make rounded diamond avatar image in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

i want to make a avatar for profile page but i couldn't add round my rectangle. I used the **ShapeableImageView** but when i rotate it 45 degrees, it rotates in the picture. Now my avatar image like this:

[image]

but i want to make like this my avatar:

[image]

How can i make rounded diamond image in android ?
my style code is here:

```
<style name="diamondavatar" parent="ShapeAppearance.Material3.SmallComponent">
            <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
            <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    
</style>
```